# Is there a way to create a timestamped log of transactions for a postgres (PG-admin) database table?

Tags: postgresql

How can I (using PG-Admin) access or create a log (ideally timestamped) that displays the changes that have happened to a table?

Answer (score 0):

First of the way enable `pg_stat_statements` on PostgreSQL.

```
create extension pg_stat_statements;
```

After then you can view all SQL queries executed on your DB. At this you can view when executed SQL, when finished, duration of execute times and etc.
For more details: [PostgreSQL Documentation - pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html)

If you need history of updated or deleted records on the tables, you can do it for all tables manually writing triggers or own functions, using JSON(JSONB) data types.